# Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin has been blocked (CORS error)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, amazon-s3, lambda, cors

I am creating a form and user should fill it up and submit. Upon submit data reaches to an email.

Deployment of form is done on S3. After submit, request goes to a function which is in lambda. Lambda function is exposed as rest endpoint using API gateway.

Hitting with postman gives success but when i am hitting it with chrome browser it gave me an error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '**endpoint Url which is getting hit while
>   submitting (given by lambda)**' from origin '**website URL where submit is
>   clicked**' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field
>   access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I searched on web and everywhere the error is resolved by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Access-Control-Allow-headers. This is in lambda

```
"headers": { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://www.websiteDummy.com',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST', 
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
            },
```

ON Fromt end side, my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            url: "deployed URL given by lambda/beta",
            data: JSON.stringify(requestJson),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType :"application/json",
            success: function(msg){

                alert("Your query is registered with us");
                document.getElementById("name").value="";
                document.getElementById("email").value="";
                document.getElementById("remarks").value="";
            }

            });
```

Adding screenshot of the network tab in chrome:
[image: Network request response for CORS]

I am not getting where is the issue. It will be helpful if anyone can even point out what might be the reason

Comment: "in preflight response" — Sounds like your code isn't running for the preflight response, only for the follow up POST response (which never happens because the browser doesn't get the OK from the preflight). You need to debug this properly. Look at the request the browser is making. Look at the response. Add logging to lambda to make sure it is running. etc.

Comment: `crossDomain: true,` — This is pointless. It has no effect unless you are making a *same origin* request which gets **redirected** to be cross origin.

Comment: Just make sure that, CORS option in s3 is enabled.

Comment: `headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },` — This is just wrong. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header, it has no place being on the request.

Comment: @ManzoorSamad — The Ajax request is being made to the Lambda, not to the S3 bucket.

Comment: Do you have a page which has a form and an iframe inside it?

Comment: Is the OPTIONS request enabled for the API gateway end point? If so can you look at the Default 4XX headers?

Comment: How you call the lambda function, with AWS sdk or API Gateway?

Comment: If you are using API gateway, check whether CORS enabled or not. One thing I would like to mention is that there is no need to put CORS header values on the request header, it's part of the response header.

Comment: @ManzoorSamad calling using API gateway exposed API directly in Jquery.

Comment: @nightgaunt yes i have enabled default Cors permission in API gateway level too.

Comment: @LajosArpad yes we have a web form and api exposed using gateway is getting called using Jquery Ajax.

Comment: @ManzoorSamad we are calling Lambda function not S3.

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta I am saying CORS option on the API Gateway level

Comment: add this key to your response header.
 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "my-origin.com"

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the network tab while making the request. Please look into it.

Comment: Removing headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' } and clearing cache from cloudfront (CDN) did it. Thanks @Quentin